# Extract temperature data from NC files in a loop

Tags: r, loops, extract, netcdf, ncdf4

I'm looking to extract some climate data from .nc files in R.d I've managed to make my code run for extracting data from a single file but I've got many different .nc files from which I'd like to extract a the entire time series of data from specific latitude and longitude points.

My .nc files have global daily resolution of temperature, so each .nc file represents a day over my study period of 10 years. All files are named the same except for the date that varies daily, e.g., gloaltemp_20000101.nc, globaltemp_20000102.nc and so on.

I'd like to extract temperature data from specific latitude and longitude points from a separate dataset of biological observations so ideally I'd like to get all the time series of temperature data for each biological observation (specific lat and long) from the NC files with global resolution (5 km x 5 km).I assume here I'll need some interpolation from my specific points to their nearest grid centre (bit lost with it).

I think it would make my life easier to extract the data using a loop but I am a bit stuck, this is the code to extract data for a single NC file.

```
folder <-"D:/TMP"
files <- list.files(folder, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

our_nc_data <- nc_open("2000/globaltemp_20000101")
print(our_nc_data)
attributes(our_nc_data$var)
attributes(our_nc_data$dim)
lat <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "lat")
lon <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "lon")

print(c(nlon, nlat))

time <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "time")
tunits <- ncatt_get(our_nc_data, "time", "units") 

gb_array <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "temperature")
fillvalue <- ncatt_get(our_nc_data, "temperature", "_FillValue")
dim(lswt_array)
gb_array[gb_array==fillvalue$value] <- NA
gb_array

tunits

time_obs <- as.POSIXct(time, origin = "1981/01/01", tz="GMT")
dim(time_obs)
range(time_obs)
dim(gb_array)
print (gb_array)

lonlattime <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lon,lat,time_obs)) 

gb_vec_long <- as.vector(gb_array)
length(gb_vec_long) 

#Create data.frame

gb_obs <- data.frame(cbind(lonlattime, lswt_vec_long))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Consider wrapping most of that code (after the attributes calls) in a `function()` and then using something like `lapply()` over your data set with said function

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of 542goweast could be implemented like this:

```
folder <-"D:/TMP"
files <- list.files(folder, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

read_my_files = function(current_file) {
    our_nc_data <- nc_open(current_file)

    ## do the reading and processing

    ## return the data frame for the current file
    data.frame(cbind(lonlattime, lswt_vec_long))
}

## this will give you a list of data frames, each containing data for
## one input file
all_data = lapply(files, read_my_files)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give it a go and will let you know if it worked!